# Calling a Function in MasterView after dismissing the ModalView in ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I am using Master-Detail template for ipad. I have a ViewController, which I want to show modally so I have used this code

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];       
        m_ViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
        m_ViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

        [appDelegate.splitViewController presentModalViewController:m_ViewController animated:YES];
```

This works fine and the ViewController is loaded modally, Now I tried to dismiss this ViewController, So inside ViewController.m, I called this line of code

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This code also works fine and the ViewController gets dismissed, **But after dismissing I want to call a function in my MasterView. How to do that?**

Code added according to the discussion with Moxy.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [appDelegate.testViewController testfunction:testImage];
```

Comment: You have to use NSNotification or create a delegate of MasterView and call it from here.

Comment: if I dont create it , it will be not called, But I want to know, why it doesnt call VieWillAppear of MasterView?

Comment: You can make use of the delegate pattern

Comment: I think it's calling -viewWillAppear: of UISplitViewController

Comment: what if I call performSelectorOnMainThreadFunction.Whether this will also call UISplitViewController?

Comment: Use one of Three ways  1. Completion section of animation for dismiss 2. use Delegate 3.Use Notification.

Answer (score 1):

As amit3117 pointed out, you should use a delegate.
The protocol should be defined at least with a method that would communicate to the delegate that the view controller that was presented modally did finish its work.

```
@class ViewController;

@protocol MyViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)viewControllerDidFinish:(ViewController *)sender;

@end
```

EDIT : I forgot to add that you should a public property for the delegate to ViewController

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MyViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

You could use your master view controller as the delegate. So in your master view controller implementation you would also have :

```
@interface MyMasterViewController () <MyViewControllerDelegate>
@end

@implementation MyMasterViewController

-(void)showViewController
{
    m_ViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" 
                                                        bundle:nil];
    m_ViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    m_ViewController.delegate = self;
    // –presentModalViewController:animated: is deprecated!
    [self.parentViewController presentViewController:m_ViewController
                                            animated:YES
                                          completion:nil];
}

-(void)viewControllerDidFinish:(ViewController *)sender
{
    // Add any code you want to execute before dismissing the modal view controller
    // –dismissModalViewController:animated: is deprecated!
    [self.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                                  completion:^{
                                                     // code you want to execute after dismissing the modal view controller
                                                  }];
}
@end
```

When `m_ViewController` finishes its work, it should call :

```
[self.delegate viewControllerDidFinish:self];
```

Comment: it is not working..My ViewController is not calling the delegate function in MasterView.

Comment: Did you see that I made an edit? I added the delegate property to ViewController and you should make it call [self.delegate viewControllerDidFinish:self]; when it's done

Comment: ey I did thatm but still it doesnt work, I tried for my otherViewControllers and it works , it only doesnt work for parentviewController.

Comment: You mean accessing the split view controller from the property in the app delegate?

Comment: Hey, I am developing an Universal app, so for ipad, I check condition if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    { }. If I write this [self.delegate viewControllerDidFinish:self]; here it doesnt work, but if I write this in else condition for iphone, it works...any suggestion?

Comment: Try [sender.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{/ code you want to execute after dismissing the modal view controller}]; instead of self.parentViewController

Comment: I am using appdelegate directly to call the ViewController and a specific function of that ViewController. is that fine?

Comment: It's not enough at all! People need to see the implementation in order to help you not the method's signature.

Comment: I just used this, and it calls the desired function.